# Invalid JAVA_HOME While Running Android sdkmanager

Tags: android-sdk-manager

I'm using Linux and I was trying to run this command

```
sudo /home/username/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
```

But I got the following error

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oraclexxx

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

But when I tried `echo $JAVA_HOME`, the output is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/`. I also have added `JAVA_HOME` in `~/.bashrc` and reload it, but still not worked.

How to set the `JAVA_HOME` variable for Android SDK Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Is the directory /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oraclexxx the root directory of your JRE? If not you need to set JAVA_HOME to your JRE. Check out this article on how to set JAVA_HOME https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/setting-java_home